# Backup: Wash machine above is too powerful?

Tags: plumbing

Debris from the above unit's washing machine clogs the line between my ground floor unit and the above unit, causing water from the drain pipe in my unit will overflow onto the floor. Plumbers that I have hired have snaked the line, and all is good until the between-unit pipe gets clogged again.
The between-unit pipe is not up to 2023 code in terms of diameter, but the HOA does not have to replace with acceptable pipe, since old pipes are grandfathered in.
Plumbers I have hired have said it would probably help to jet the line. I presume they mean the pipe from my laundry to the condo building's main line, and not the pipe between units.
The HOA refuses to jet anything, though they paid a plumber to snake and unclog the pipe between units, thereby at least tempoarily solving the overflow problem. They claim that the problem is almost certainly to be caused by the above tenant having a "too large" washing machine.
Indeed, it is true that I have observed the overflow occurring when upstairs tenant was using his washing machine.
Therefore, they claim that I should ask the above tenant to solve the overflow problem somehow, and presumably pay for any damages to the drywall that has occurred in my laundry.
But the above tenant has not been negligent.
I don't think it was his responsibility to test the wash machine to see if it caused problems in my unit before he bought it, and indeed, he does not know at this point that the washing machine is causing the overflow in my unit from time to time. Presumably the original pipes in the condo building are not wide enough to accommodate the larger, more modern wash machines, but that is not the fault of the above tenant.
My question is whether any sort of jetting would likely help? And who is responsible for repairs and damages? The water that has overflowin onto my laundry floor has also dripped and damaged drywall and created mold.

Comment: Who is HOA?  Well, either you clean the inter-unit pipes, replace the pipes or talk to your neighbour.  I don't see any other choices.

Comment: This might become more of a lawyer/legal question.  If the HOA "owns" those pipes and they are causing damage to your unit, you and your neighbours might have a case.  Will need a good lawyer to go over the contracts/CCRs/whatever there is between you and the HOA.

Comment: Is it possible that the debris is coming from something else? Non-flushable wipes, for example. The debris is probably hooking on something and collecting. Did the plumbers use a camera to see that the pipes are smooth (i.e. errant screw, etc.)? I would expect the back-up to be to the upstairs if it's too much water and restriction is between units, so debris is possibly further down the line.

Comment: "who is responsible for repairs and damages?" is a legal question and not on-topic here (or at [law.se]). You'll have to read your HOA agreement to find out.

Comment: Since when does ANY washing machine discharge any significant "debris"?. That being the cause of backups is totally not believable. Modern machines do tend to have a larger output volume, which can overwhelm old undersize drain piping, especially if it is old steel and therefore almost certainly semi-blocked with rust/corrosion. If the pipes are that bad, the HOA should institute a rule requiring flow restrictors on washing machine outputs.